# JupyterHub - log current user

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I use a custom logger to log who is currently doing any kind of stuff in Jupyterhub.

```
logging_config: dict = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "company": {
            "()": lambda: MyFormatter(user=os.environ.get("JUPYTERHUB_USER", "Unknown"))
        },
    },
....

c.Application.logging_config = logging_config
```

Output:
`{"asctime": "2022-06-29 14:13:43,773", "level": "WARNING", "name": "JupyterHub", "message": "Updating Hub route http://127.0.0.1:8081 \u2192 http://jupyterhub:8081", "user": "Unknown"`

The logger itself works fine, but I am not able to log who was performing the action. In the Image I start, there is a `JUPYTERHUB_USER` env variable available. This seems to get passed from JupyterHub ( I don´t know how this is done exactly). But in JupyterHub I don´t have this variable available.

Is there a way to use it in JupyterHub, not just in the jupyterLab container?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't get you all the way there but it's a start - we add extra pod annotations/labels through KubeSpawner's [`extra_annotations`](https://jupyterhub-kubespawner.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.0/spawner.html#kubespawner.KubeSpawner.extra_annotations) using the `cluster_options` hook (see our [helm chart](https://github.com/RhodiumGroup/daskhub-rhg-config/blob/1f211cb7bcf191c3056c9316442ef30801136dec/daskhub-rhg/values.yaml#L217-L222) for our complete daskhub setup):

```py
  dask-gateway:
    gateway:
      extraConfig:
        optionHandler: |
          from dask_gateway_server.options import Options, String, Select, Mapping, Float, Bool
          from math import ceil
          def cluster_options(user):
              def option_handler(options):
                  extra_annotations = {
                      "hub.jupyter.org/username": user.name
                  }
                  default_extra_labels = {
                      "hub.jupyter.org/username": user.name,
                  }

              return Options(
                  Select(
                      ...
                  ),
                  ...,
                  handler=option_handler,
              )
          c.Backend.cluster_options = cluster_options
```

You can then poll pods with these labels to get real time usage. There may be a more direct way to do this though - not sure.